# Proper course of action after editing downvoted question to get it answered

Tags: discussion, edits, questions, humor, downvoted-questions

After reading hundreds of boring to-the-point questions, I asked [this legitimate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627904/how-to-build-a-database-from-an-xsd-schema-and-import-xml-records) on XSD and XML schemas, sprinkled with Pulp Fiction and unicorn references. Needless to say my question was immediately downvoted for being too sparkly.

Now, I don't want to start *yet another thread* on why humorous questions aren't popular, so I edited out all <strike>funny</strike>dark humour (even from the title), but now I fear my question will be ignored after being downvoted.

What is the best course of action to get my question answered? Obviously re-asking is wrong, but waiting for a benevolent soul to realize it's a useful question could take forever.

Comment: Cut back on all that bold for one. (It was way too much on the first version of your question on SO.)

Comment: @random my bad. I usually add some to highlight keywords and help readers skim. Wasn't appropriate here.

Comment: Revision 1 made me honestly laugh aloud, but, uh, yeah, not quite what's normally expected on SO.

Comment: :( I want to see it! The Google cache only has the revised version.

Comment: @balpha: Stop checking Meta and get that last 3k [!](http://codepad.org/xLj454Ex)

Comment: @Gnome: lol -- working on it. Thanks for exclamating that point to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow. Uh.. wow.

I would delete that one and start over with a new question, personally.

Humor is good, but generally in small doses only. A little goes a long way. And it helps when it's.. er.. actually funny? :)

Comment: Thanks. I've been reading some of the existing posts on the SO community's feelings toward my black humour (not like that) and I gotta bite the bullet on this one. So you learn.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want your question answered? Try to not offend anyone, leave out humor as much as possible (it's a technical site, not a stand-up comedy club*) and be as detailed as possible.

<sub>* does not apply to meta</sub>

Comment: So this is a stand-up comedy club? Well, that explains a lot...

Comment: @Ladybug Killer hey, you want to hear the one about the pony, the unicorn and the gay horse?

Comment: They are all the same.